# How do you subtract (X) of Days from (CurrentDateTime) then check with another Date

Tags: crystal-reports, sap

I am currently working with Crystal Reports XI and I am trying to make a formula that highlights ship dates that are withing 72 hours of the current date time. How would I go about making a formula that would perform that function?

My guess would be but I do not know how to go about it

```
{TableName.ShipDate} <= CurrentDatetime - 72 Hours
    then crYellow
```

Comment: If `{TableName.ShipDate} <= CurrentDateTime And [TableName.ShipDate} >= CurrentDateTime - 72 Hours`. That is essentially a fool proof way since I don't know if your table displays future ship dates. If it only shows ship dates that have only happened, you could use `{TableName.ShipDate} >= CurrentDateTime - 72 Hours`. This method doesn't protect against future dates.

Comment: Not sure if it worked but I am not getting the results I wanted. I am just trying to create a format that if the ShipDate is within 3 days it will change the color by comparing the time between now and the ShipDate, if it is within 72 hours of the ShipDate then turn Yellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IF {Table.ShipDate} <= CurrentDateTime
then crRed
ELSE

IF ({Table.ShipDate} - 3) <= CurrentDateTime
then crYellow

ELSE

crNoColor;
```

Comment: Mark your answer as answer.